how long should i run a training to realize how well an NN model is doing?
Suppose I am manually tuning the hyperparameters of an NN model.
How many epochs of training should I run at a minimum to realize that the model won't give me the desired accuracy I need before stopping the training?
E.g., if a training starts with an accuracy of 75%, I cannot expect it to reach 90% after 1000 epochs of training. can I?
So, how should I use my intuition?

Stop training the model when the chosen validation metric (loss, accuracy, whatever) stops improving for some number of epochs ("patience"). It's up to you to decide how patient you're willing to be.

Depends on models size and dataset size. Large Language Models are trained for months. If you have a simple Multilayer Perceptron model it could take minutes.
I think it's possible to have 75% after one epoch and 90% after 1000 epochs.
If you don't have experience with the specific model and data size, I wouldn't rely on intuition too much. You can look at the the accuracy increase from epoch to epoch and see if there's still improvement. This may be noisy so typically what is done you look at some smoothed / running average of the performance, like here in Tensorboard,
.

I am using biological tabular data.
